# How to use Pandas to match the order of data

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have two datasets which are in the text file format like that.

[image]

The first column is the user ID and the final column is the feature. The two files are in shape (500k, 3) and (480k, 3). The second file is included in the first file. I want to match the same user ID order and delete the missing ones. How can I do this efficiently?

Comment: So you would like to keep only those entries which exist in the second file, but you would like them to be ordered as they are in the first? I assume the order is different in the two files.

Comment: @g.a You are right and I try to use the dictionary to solve this problem. I am not sure if there is a smarter way.

Comment: convert both the txt files to dataframes. using pandas pd.merge(how='inner') between both the dataframes, you can achieve this very easily.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something on the below lines should solve it.

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.read_csv('your_file1.txt',sep=' ',names=['col1','col2','col3'])
df2 = pd.read_csv('your_file2.txt',sep=' ',names=['col1','col2','col3'])

df1.merge(df2,how='inner',on='col1')
```